# Enabling Graceful shutdown for SpringBoot app does not take effect

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to enable graceful shutdown for my app

I added following settings to application.properties :

```
server.shutdown=graceful
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=1m
```

So here, as I understand, expected period after shutdown happens is 1 min - i.e. the app can get requests within 1 min after shutdown - is it correct ?
For test I also enabled `/actuator/shutdown` endpoint. And when I access via Postman to the
/actuator/shutdown , I see the app ending immediately, here is log

```
05 08:55:24.741 | Thread-14            | 325 | INFO  |   |o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown.shutDownGracefully [53] - Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete
05 08:55:24.921 | tomcat-shutdown      | 325 | INFO  |   |o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.GracefulShutdown.doShutdown [78] - Graceful shutdown complete
05 08:55:24.922 | Thread-14            | 325 | INFO  |   |o.a.catalina.core.StandardService.log [173] - Stopping service [Tomcat]
05 08:55:24.925 | Thread-14            | 325 | INFO  |   |o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/bff].log [173] - Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet
```

Springboot version : 2.7.15
Is there missing here something in config? Thanks in advance

Comment: No your understanding is wrong. If there is anything blocking the shutdown that will be timed out after 1 minute to proceed with the shutdown. Currently there are no active requests so the shutdown can be done directly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually , if there is no running blocking thread in tomcat thread pool , it is normally that close the sever immediately when you stop the  server.

you can use the following code snippet for test .

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ShutdownController {

    private volatile boolean shutdownRequested = false;

    @GetMapping("/graceful-shutdown-test")
    public String gracefulShutdownTest() {
        // Simulate a long-running process
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (shutdownRequested) {
                return "Shutdown requested. Cleaning up...";
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulate some work
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        return "Process completed successfully!";
    }

    // Endpoint to trigger a graceful shutdown
    @GetMapping("/trigger-shutdown")
    public String triggerShutdown() {
        shutdownRequested = true;
        return "Shutdown requested. It may take some time to complete ongoing tasks.";
    }
}
```

try to  request the REST API , and when it is blocking , close the server , it would wait  for all the thread is done which is in tomcat thread pool . that is graceful shutdown